# How to protect a controller in a Spree extention so that only the admin of the shop can access it?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am trying to develop a Quote Extention for Spree, allowing customers to upload files to AWS S3.

I would like to "secure" via authentication some of its actions and Spree provides useful helpers to that end, however I couldn't manage to get it to work.
As far as I understood the matter, I have to add this line in the QuotesController. 
`include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth`
in my controller, as shown in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adoptanoob/ced3921d3033a4b11647)

Unfortunately, I still get the undefined method error authenticate_user!

For the sake of keeping this thread DRY, you can find more on my question on [Spree's repository issue #5794](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5794)

Any contribution is very welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could delete the question since it was based upon wrong assumptions, but I rather detail how I managed to solve the authentication of the QuotesController.

Many thanks to @Hates_ and all the people in the Spree IRC for their answers!

The first wrong assumption was in regard to the design of the QuotesController which should be split up in 2 parts one for the customers, one for the shop admin backend. The second wrong assumption was that the `include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Auth` was not going to give me the protection I wanted. So here is what I ended up with:

**The Admin Side**

In Spree, in order to have your controller enjoy the "protection" of the admin of the shop, this controller has to inherit like that `Spree::Admin::QuotesController < Spree::Admin::BaseController`. This controller would live in `app/controllers/spree/admin/quotes_controller.rb`. This is all you need to "protect" it. Also, it will make your views integrate into the shop's backend nicely.

**The Customer Side**

It is better, by design, to make another QuotesController using a different namespace `app/controllers/spree/quotes_controller.rb` and inheriting like that:

`Spree::QuotesController < Spree:Core::BaseController`